# Error in jquery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, timeout

This code is supposed to produce the following effect: when `.expander` is moused over, it waits 400 milliseconds and then expands to 150% of its original size over the course of 270 milliseconds. If the mouse leaves `.expander`, the expansion is cancelled.

```
<div class="expander"><%=image_tag("expander.jpg")%></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".expander").on('mouseenter', function () {
    $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function () {
      $(this).stop(true, true).animate({width: "150%"}, 270, function() {});
    }, 400));
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({width: "150%"}, 270, function() {});
  });
</script>
```

When I mouse over `.expander`, nothing happens. However, when my mouse leaves `.expander`, it grows. So the second part of the code must be fine. Does anyone see any problems with the first part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loosing context `this` inside `setTimeout`. You can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind callback function to proper context:

```
$.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        width: "150%"
    }, 270, function () {});
}.bind(this), 400));
```

If you care about IE8 support, use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) - simple bind implementation.

```
$.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        width: "150%"
    }, 270, function () {});
}, this), 400));
```

Comment: Also, if you are having a hard time with `bind` and `proxy`, you can set `this` to a variable and then use it wherever. For example `function () { var that = this;  setTimeout(function () { $(that).stop() }, 400); }`